# jQuery fadeIn fails with jqQuery form-plugin

Tags: jquery, forms, message, fadein

I have a message that I want to fadeIn when a form is successfully send. I'm using the jQuery form plugin and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var options = {
target: '#output',
beforeSubmit: validate,
resetForm: true
}; 
$('#holdform').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

The validate function works perfectly so i added this code before it returns **true**:
(...)

```
$('#output').fadeIn('slow');
return true;    
}
```

This should fadeIn the div I have underneath the form, styled as display: none;.
But what happens is that the div fades in and then disappears. Does anyone have an explanation and possibly a solution to fix it?  Thank you in advance!

The code can be seen in it error-action here: http://gadebold.dk/events/tilmeld/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is the content is being replaced.  You're fading in the `#output` div, but when the server response comes back, the form plugin is putting that response in `#output` because that's what you have the target set to.

If you don't care about the server response, just remove the `target` option and it won't replace it's content, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    beforeSubmit: validate,
    resetForm: true
  }; 
  $('#holdform').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

[See here for a full list of options](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object)

Comment: Still new to how all these plugins work, but this just got me one step further in the right direction! thanks alot